# VS Code can't find git-rebase-todo

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Running Pop OS 22.04 I can't do `git rebase -i main` from the VS Code terminal, when opening the file VS Code says:

> The editor could not be opened because the file was not found.

It's correctly opening the path, but it believes file doesn't exist.

```
•❭ git config --get core.editor
code --wait
```

I tried manually running `code --wait .git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo` but as the file is already "open" it didn't open again (I assume). I can `cat` the file just fine from the VS Code terminal.

Any ideas what could be wrong?